# Normal string with "xe2x80x93" "-" char

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, unicode-escapes

I have a problem with strings in **python3**. my var **g** is a normal string. But in it there is an annoying **"xe2x80x93"**, because it comes from a web parser. I would like to convert this to the fitting character **"-"**.

```
content = str(urllib.request.urlopen(site, timeout=10).read())
g = content.split('<h1 itemprop="name"')[1].split('</span></h1>')[0].split('<span>')[1].replace("\\", "")

print(type(g)) --> string
print(g)  --> "Flash xe2x80x93 der rote Blitz"

print(g.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')) --> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
print(repr(g.decode('unicode-escape'))) --> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
print(g.encode('ascii','replace')) --> b'Flash xe2x80x93 der rote Blitz'
print(bytes(g, "utf-8").decode()) --> "Flash xe2x80x93 der rote Blitz"
print(bytes(g, "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")) --> "Flash â der rote Blitz"
```

How can it works? I dont get any further.

Comment: What does `print(type(urllib.request.urlopen(site, timeout=10).read()))` say?

Comment: <class 'bytes'>, so i have to use ".decode("utf-8") ", instead of str() ?

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my answer to give you a replacement first line that should work for you.

Comment: Lukas, yep -- try it at let me / us know how it goes :)

Comment: Yeah it works! @jedwards. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, if you're problem is solved please consider marking an answer as correct (whether it be mine, your own or someone else's) so future helper gremlins like yours truly can safely skip the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea with `decode`.

By wrapping the output in `str(...)` in this line:

```
content = str(urllib.request.urlopen(site, timeout=10).read())
```

You're either converting a bytes object to a string (which will be evident by a leading `b'` and trailing `'` in the `content`), or, if it's already been decoded as ISO-8859-1, doing nothing.

In either case, don't do that -- remove the wrapping `str` call.

Now, content will be either a `bytes` object or a `str` object.

So if it's a string, it'll be already decoded (incorrectly) as ISO-8859-1.  You'll want to encode it back to a bytes object, then decode it correctly:

```
content = urllib.request.urlopen(site, timeout=10).read()

if isinstance(content, str):
    content = content.encode('iso-8859-1')
content = content.decode('utf8')
```

Now, your `\xe2\x80\x93` bytes should properly show up as: –

**Update**:

From your comment, all you need to do is:

```
content = urllib.request.urlopen(site, timeout=10).read().decode('utf8')
```